# How to add the item to ADTSorted list by value not position

Tags: java, data-structures, adt, sortedlist

So I am creating a SortedDoubleList which is the sorted ADT List. For inserting the object into the array I have:

```
Public void ListInsert(int posi, int newItem){

    throws RuntimeException, IndexOutOfBoundsException{
        if (numItems>=LISTSIZE) {
            //statment
            throw new RuntimeException("List is full and you cannot add new item");

        }else{
            //shift element 
            if (posi>=1 and posi<=numItems+1) {
                //backward
                for (int i=numItems; i>=posi ; i-- ) {
                    items[i]=items[i-1];    
                }
                items[posi-1]=newItem;
                numItems++;


            }else{
                throws new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index of new item to be inserted out of bound")
            }
        }

    } 

}
```

But instead of adding by the position I want to add by **VALUE**. For example when you insert an item into a sorted list you do not specify where in the list the item belongs. Instead, the insertion operation determines the correct position of the item by comparing its value with those of the existing items on the list. The number is also a double! Do you have any thought on this?
Thanks

Comment: "by comparing its value with those of the existing items on the list" - yes, do that. Have you tried to write code to do this yet?

Comment: I think I need a function to determines from the value of an item its numerical position?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean insert by value? It's not possible to specify the position because the list will be unsorted. Imagine you try to insert 3 in the second position into this list {1,2,4}, the list would be {1,3,2,4}.

Comment: I want insert and deletion be by value not by position. I explained it in the bottom of code as well!

Comment: Then choose another structure that do not sort. Why do you use ADTSorted?

Comment: Its my school project! I need to use the ADT Sorted List as a purpose!

Comment: Maybe you have to implement another comparison function

Comment: Nevermind I think I got it. I need a function like LocateIndex to determines from the value of an item its numerical position. Thanks for help